# How to display an image associated with a clicked list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with a school project. I have a catClicker app that displays an image of a cat and the number of times the image has been clicked.

Now I have to display the names of five different cats. When a cat's name is clicked, I have to update the image and counter for that cat.

This is what I've done so far:

https://github.com/silvodesigns/catClicker

Comment: Simple. Just have a dictionary with your model in js.js that uses the names as keys and then just increment model[name].

Comment: The counter for the image does work correctly. So now you want to change the image as well on clicking the image names and render its counter as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change your cats object like this

```
var cats = {'Tabby' : {'count' : 0, 'src' : 'img/Cat01.jpg'}, 'Tiger' : {'count' : 0, 'src' : 'img/Cat02.jpg'}};
```

Explanation : 
We are keeping the cat name as the key to the individual cat properties so we can fetch them using the cat name on click.

> For your event handler

```
   $("ul#cats>li").on("click", function(){
     var name = $(this).html();
     var src = cats[name].src;
     $('img.cat').attr('src',src);
     cats[name].count = cats[name].count + 1;
    });
```

Explanation :

Jquery is being used as i can see you are using jquery.js.

1. We fetch the name using html property.
2. We then pass it as the key to cats object to get the property such as name and count.

Note:  I have added only two cats , add more if you have them :D

Answer (score 0):

Register a click event handler on the image container (use event delegation).

On each click increment the counter, in that way you can maintain the number of clicks.

On click of name, do the same. Register a click event handler and on click get the image name from the event.target and then change the main image as per it.

Answer (score 0):

There is many solution to do the same. Here is the solution from my side.
Your previous code for appending the name is:

```
for(var i=0; i< catNames.length; i++){
 $('#cats').append('<li>'+ catNames[i].name +'</li>');// loop over the names of the cats and create and append it to the ul on Index.html
 }
```

I make a little change. Used  data attribute to stored the index for each name (li)

```
for(var i=0; i< catNames.length; i++){
 $('#cats').append('<li data-index="'+i+'" class="names">'+ catNames[i].name +'</li>');// loop over the names of the cats and create and append it to the ul on Index.html
 }
```

and your onclick target is different as previous:

```
$('.cat').click(function(){// whenever the picture with class .cat is clicked the counter goes up
catNames[model.currentCat].clickCount ++;
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
counter.innerHTML = catNames[model.currentCat].clickCount;

}
```

The update version for the click event is like this:
** i used names as class for each li

```
$('.names').click(function(){
// whenever the picture with class .cat is clicked the counter goes up

var index=parseInt($(this).data("index"));
var image=catNames[index].imgSrc;



//This line count individual click for each
    catNames[index].clickCount=    catNames[index].clickCount+1


    catNames[model.currentCat].clickCount ++;
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    counter.innerHTML = catNames[model.currentCat].clickCount;
    $('.cat').attr('src',image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that when an HTML list item is clicked, the click handler has to figure out which logical cat object it should update.

Here is a simple solution: when you make the list item, add a property that refers to the cat object.

Like this:

```
var listItem = $('<li>').html(cat.name);
$('#catList').append(listItem);
listItem = listItem[0];  // Extract the DOM element from the jQuery object.
listItem.cat = cat;      // Add a reference to the logical cat object.
listItem.onclick = function () {
  var cat = this.cat;    // When the list item is clicked, get the cat object.
  cat.clickCount++;      // Increment the counter and update the display.
  $('#displayClickedCat').html(
      '<p id="counter">' + cat.name + ' has ' + cat.clickCount +
      ' click' + (cat.clickCount == 1 ? '' : 's') +
      '.</p>' + '<img src="' + cat.src + '" class="cat" />');
};
```

The snippet below demonstrates this approach.

```js
var imageDirectory =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silvodesigns/catClicker/master/img/';
var model = {
  startCat: 0,
  cats: [
    { name: 'Tabby', src: imageDirectory + 'Cat01.jpg' },
    { name: 'Scaredy', src: imageDirectory + 'Cat02.jpg' },
    { name: 'Sleepy', src: imageDirectory + 'Cat03.jpg' },
    { name: 'Shadow', src: imageDirectory + 'Cat04.jpg' },
    { name: 'Tiger', src: imageDirectory + 'Cat05.jpg' }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  var cats = model.cats;
  for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
    var cat = cats[i];
    cat.clickCount = 0;
    var listItem = $('<li>').html(cat.name);
    $('#catList').append(listItem);
    listItem = listItem[0];  // Extract the DOM element from the jQuery object.
    listItem.cat = cat;      // Add a reference to the logical cat object.
    listItem.onclick = function () {
      var cat = this.cat;    // When the list item is clicked, get the cat object.
      cat.clickCount++;      // Increment the counter and update the display.
      $('#displayClickedCat').html(
          '<p id="counter">' + cat.name + ' has ' + cat.clickCount +
          ' click' + (cat.clickCount == 1 ? '' : 's') +
          '.</p>' + '<img src="' + cat.src + '" class="cat" />');
    };
    if (i == model.startCat) {
      cat.clickCount = -1;
      listItem.onclick();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
img {
}
#catList {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#catList li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#catList li:hover {
  border-color: #888;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="displayNames">
  <ul id="catList"></ul>
</div>

<div id="displayClickedCat"></div>
```